# Insert Statement for List

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I'm not too sure how to describe my SQL Insert statement so I will describe the expected result.

I'm building a data extract list and have a table that I've put all my data into.  It's called _MATTER_LIST

[image]

What I am trying to Achieve is to have the Client_Number + Col1 combination repeat after every unique COL1+COL2+COL3 combination but not duplicate when there is already a CLIENT_NUMBER+COL1.  So the end result would be:

thanks in advance for any tips.

[image]

Comment: tag the DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc...) which u r using.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `ORDER BY` should work for you if i understand. Try this :

```
select Client_Number, Col1, Col2, Col3 from _MATTER_LIST
order by Client_Number, Col1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix my own issue.  I added a unique key for the col1 + col2 + col3 , then make col2 repeat over each combination for example.
The result is:  select * from _MATTER_LIST order by COL4, COL5
[image]

Comment: To get to this point, without a unique key, you can use ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION BY. (Maybe handy for future cases)

Comment: You do know that you won't necessarily get the data ordered by anything you don't specify in the `ORDER BY` clause even with an index?  It might, but it might not.  Don't rely on it.